# How does log() differentiate between log base and natural log?

Tags: c++, function, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I am new to coding, and am a bit confused by how C++ differentiates between log base (any number) and natural log (base e) if both are represented by the same `log()` function. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Please don't post an entire question in the post title. The title should be terse. The body of the post should contains a clear question, not just pleasantries.

Comment: Are you sure of this? I was under the impression that `log` was base e, `log10` was base 10, and that there was a small family of other log functions.

Comment: In C++, `log()` and `log10()` are distinct functions with different names.    An expression like `log10(x)` is not specified as being a call to `log()` with a base of `10`.

Answer (score 2):

The Google's Internet Search Engine top result for phrase ""c++ log", fully answers your question :

using tgmath.h

**natural**

- double log (double x);

**binary**

- double log2  (double x);
- float log2f (float x);
- long double log2l (long double x);

**base 10**

- double log10 (double x);

To conclude, different bases have different function names.

Comment: Please note that <cmath> already contains all the necessary overloads, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log10